# Excel IF function based on cell comment text

Tags: excel-formula

I'm not sure its possible, but what I'd like to do would be to check a cell's comment text for a specific string in an IF function

i.e.  `=IF(MID(CellA.CommentText,3,3) = "XYZ", {True},{False})`

Comment: You can't get cell comment with only default formula. Please define a user define formula for it.

Comment: https://chandoo.org/wp/get-cell-comments/

Comment: @Nikita, I suspected this was the case but attempting to find an answer for it didn't turn up anything definitive and when in doubt, ask those who may know :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no Excel Formula to reference Comments without VBA User Defined Functions.

To do it this way, you would need something like this:

```vb
Public Function GetCellComment(Target As Range) AS Variant
    On Error Resume Next 'In case reference is invalid, no comment exists, etc
    GetCellComment = Target.Cells(1, 1).Comment.Text
End Function
```

(If — and *only* if — you *absolutely **need*** the function to recalculate when *any* cell in the workbook is changed, you can add the line [`Application.Volatile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Excel.Application.Volatile) before the `On Error Resume Next`.  But, overuse of this can make the workbook run slowly, so use sparingly)

And then use that within the Excel Function:

```vb
=IF(MID(GetCellComment(CellA), 3, 3) = "XYZ", {True},{False})
```